# Escape html (href) in grid extjs4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

I have to escape all the HTML in my Extjs grid. 
I used the gonfig :

```
return Ext.String.htmlEncode(value);
```

in the renderer of my column and it works like a charm for the simple html like `h1`, `b`, `i`, etc.

However, if I put the following code in a cell :

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Alert !!')"> foo </a>
```

When I click on the cell, the alert is dispatched....

How could I prevent it ?

Comment: Why are you not passing that through the renderer?

Comment: What do you mean by "through the renderer" ? Cause the renderer is set, but I cant find the way to prevent the grid from interpreting the href...

Comment: When you run that string through htmlEncode, you get `&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; onclick=&quot;alert(&#39;Alert !!&#39;)&quot;&gt; foo &lt;/a&gt;`.

Comment: That's what I do. Once I entered the `<a href="#" onclick="alert('Alert !!')"> foo </a>`, I save. Then, when I reload my page and click on the cell. The onclick is activated...

Comment: See here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232292-Escaping-HTML-characters-in-editable-grids

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this problem is here:

http://non-stop-ext.blogspot.com/2013/02/gridpanel-with-special-characters-and.html